# Online stock screener to find stocks that are negatively correlated to another stock/index?

Tags: united-states, stock-analysis, online-tools, online-data-source

Is there a free online resource that I can use to find pairs of stocks that are always negatively correlated? For example, I want to find stocks that are negatively correlated w.r.t SPY.

On Google Finance, I can draw the chart for SPY for the last 5 years, and then individually I can compare other stock charts against the SPY chart to find which ones are negatively correlated. But this is manual process and I need to select each stock to know if it is negatively correlated with SPY.

Is there an automatic tool that would let me choose one ETF like SPY, then find all other stocks that have a correlation coefficient of less than 0 with SPY?

An alternative obviously is to download historical prices and calculate the coefficient in Excel.

Comment: I'll assume you mean for U.S.-listed stocks, based on your choice of SPY.

Comment: Yes, but I am referring to both US and Canada

Comment: I know this question is old, but I'm voting to close as it seems to be attracting quasi-advertising posts like the below. Perhaps it should be locked instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Finviz](http://finviz.com/) can be screened by [beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_%28finance%29) which is an index of correlation.

Finviz covers all major North American exchanges and some others.

Answer (score 1):

There are lists with Top 1,000 Most and Less correlated stocks for different markets, I think you'll find the solution here: 
https://unicornbay.com/tools/most-less-correlated-assets

Answer (score 0):

[SeekingAlpha](http://seekingalpha.com/page/etf-finder) has a section dedicated to [Short ETFs](http://seekingalpha.com/insight/etf_hub/etf_guide/selector/article/31113-inverse-short-market-cap-etfs) as well as others. In there you will find [SH](http://stockcharts.com/h-sc/ui?s=SH&p=D&yr=0&mn=6&dy=0&id=p11771339816), and [SDS](http://stockcharts.com/h-sc/ui?s=SDS&p=D&yr=0&mn=6&dy=0&id=p64365945087).  Both of which are inverse to the S&P 500.

Edit: I linked to charts that compare SH and SDS to SPY.

Comment: Careful... these inverse products may not actually always behave the way people would like them to; see e.g http://news.morningstar.com/articlenet/article.aspx?id=271892 or http://monevator.com/short-etf-maths/

Answer (score -2):

You may want to have a look at [DiversifyPortfolio](https://www.diversifyportfolio.com) which will give you the info you want plus quite a bit more. They offer various tools all related to stock correlation and diversification.

You'll be able to create heatmaps and various other charts showing stock correlations. It also has several scans which allow you to search for stocks that meet your requirements in terms of correlation to existing positions in your portfolio or to specific stocks / ETF's.